# Index out of range error in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website and get details of the products. Some of the products have unit and some have not. The structure is something like this below:

**For products having a unit:**

```
<div class="unit">
<p>200ml</p>
</div>
```

**For products having no unit:**

```
<div class = "unit">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

My spider works something like this:

```
def product(self, response):
        products = response.xpath('descendant::*[@class="product_list_ul"]')
        item = Item()
        i = 0
        while i < 20:
            item['link'] = products.xpath(
                'descendant::*[@class="product-image"]//a/@href').extract()[i]
            item['name'] = products.xpath(
                'descendant::*[@class="product-name"]//a/@title').extract()[i]
            item['unit'] = products.xpath(
                    'descendant::*[@class="unit"]/p/text()').extract()[i]
            item['price'] = products.xpath(
                'descendant::*[@class="price"]/text()').extract()[i]
            item['image_url'] = products.xpath(
                'descendant::*[@class="product-image"]//a//img/@src').extract()[i]
            i += 1
            yield item
```

But there is a problem.

```
products.xpath('descendant::*[@class="unit"]/p/text()').extract()
```

gives only those results that have unit. For ex: If there are 5 products like this:

p1 : N/A

p2 : 200ml

p3 : 60gm

p4 : 5ml

p5 : N/A

For this I am getting a list as : **[200ml, 60gm, 5ml]**. So I am ultimately getting **"Index out of range error"**

Can someone suggest a way in which I can solve this problem and get a list as **[N/A, 200ml, 60gm, 5ml, N/A]**

**Edit:** I have figured out a way by doing a little more research but the problem is that it works on scrapy shell only.

```
[txt for item in sel.xpath('descendant::*[@class="litre"]/p') for txt in item.select('text()').extract() or [u'N/A']]
```

It gives me a list just as I want. I made the following edits to incorporate this in my python script.

```
def unit_xpath(self, product):
        x = [txt for i in sel.xpath('descendant::*[@class="litre"]/p') for txt in i.select('text()').extract() or [u'n/a']]
        return x



def product(self, response):
     products = response.xpath('descendant::*[@class="product_list_ul"]')
     item = ForestessentialsItem()
     i = 0
     while i < 20:
         item['link'] = products.xpath('descendant::*[@class="product-image"]//a/@href').extract()[i]
         item['name'] = products.xpath('descendant::*[@class="product-name"]//a/@title').extract()[i]
         item['unit'] = self.unit_xpath(products)[i]
         item['price'] = products.xpath('descendant::*[@class="price"]/text()').extract()[i]
         item['image_url'] = products.xpath('descendant::*[@class="product-image"]//a//img/@src').extract()[i]
         i += 1
         yield item
```

I am getting error  `NameError: global name 'sel' is not defined`. Can someone please tell me how can I proceed from here

Comment: regarding your `'sel' is not defined` error - you are not providing selector to your `unit_xpath(self, product)` function. It should be `unit_xpath(self, sel, product)` and when you call it `self.unit_xpath(sel, products)[i]`

Comment: Thanks @Granitosaurus I figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a way to do this.

```
def unit_xpath(self, response):
        x = [txt for item in response.xpath('descendant::*[@class="unit"]/p') for txt in item.xpath('text()').extract() or [u'N/A']]
        return x

def product(self, response):
        products = response.xpath('descendant::*[@class="product_list_ul"]')
        item = Item()
        i = 0
        while i < 20:
            item['link'] = products.xpath(
                'descendant::*[@class="product-image"]//a/@href').extract()[i]
            item['name'] = products.xpath(
                'descendant::*[@class="product-name"]//a/@title').extract()[i]
            item['unit'] = products.xpath(
                    'descendant::*[@class="unit"]/p/text()').extract()[i]
            item['price'] = products.xpath(
                'descendant::*[@class="price"]/text()').extract()[i]
            item['image_url'] = products.xpath(
                'descendant::*[@class="product-image"]//a//img/@src').extract()[i]
            i += 1
            yield item
```

Thanks to all for helping me out in this. Also thanks @Granitosaurus.. I know your way of approaching the products in group is way better but this just serves my use case.

Answer (score 0):

There's a slight flaw in your spider's logic. Usually it's possible to get list of products selectors and just iterate through them. Something like this:

```
def product(self, response):
    products = response.xpath('descendant::*[@class="product_list_ul"]')
    # [1] "//" is short for "descendant::" so you should use that instead
    products = response.xpath('//*[@class="product_list_ul"]')
    for prod in products:
        item = Item()
        item['link'] = prod.xpath('.//*[@class="product-image"]//a/@href').extract()
        item['name'] = prod.xpath('.//*[@class="product-name"]//a/@title').extract()
        item['unit'] = prod.xpath('.//*[@class="unit"]/p/text()').extract()
        item['price'] = prod.xpath('.//*[@class="price"]/text()').extract()
        item['image_url'] = prod.xpath('.//*[@class="product-image"]//a//img/@src').extract()
        yield item
```

If you could provide an url, I could provide a more concrete example.

[1] - More xpath shortcuts and descriptions: https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/xslt/xpath-axes-and-their-shortcuts/

Comment: this doesn't answer my question. :(

Comment: @theflash It does, the reason you are getting index error because you are using index with while loop while extracting every field seperately. What happens is that some products don't have field `x` and that means that list is shorter and you already lost your order, i.e. `x[14]` will not be part of 14th product. Your code is fundamentally flawed here and cannot be fixed. You need to approach the products in groups, and that's what my answer does.

Comment: I know the reason why I am getting this error, what I want to know is how can I modify this code to get the list I want

Comment: I changed my logic just as your answer says. but I am not getting any result in the unit column..can you look into this

Comment: What url are you crawling? It's difficult to see what might be the problem without html source.